# Why does swift not recognise my resource?

Tags: ios, swift, url, directory, bundle

Swift is telling me my file does not exist and unfortunately I cannot find the directory myself. Am I using the URL for resource method incorrectly or do I just need to find a way of removing the optional brackets? When I refer to this object directly it works but I need to find a way of creating a path my team mates can use as well.

```
override func setUp()
{
    super.setUp()
    let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("meetingexample", withExtension: "ics")
    let eventsFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ("\(bundleURL)"))
    //let eventsFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docFolderURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/meetingexample.ics"))
    content = try! String(contentsOfURL: eventsFile, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    
}
```

Print of bundleURL:

***Optional(file:/Users/GB112922/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF6A2594-6B31-4E38-B46D-2F3AAAF25210/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/35E04003-072F-476E-957E-98C70B792539/CallIn.app/meetingexample.ics)`***

Comment: @rmaddy Yes to both questions in your first comment. Just using bundleURL gives me an error as it's expecting a string rather than a NSURL.

Comment: Although it is in the a testing folder rather than in the main app's folder, perhaps this could have an impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `"\(bundleURL)"` is wrapping the value of the `NSURL` in the `Optional(...)` extra text.
2. `URLForResource` is already giving you an `NSURL`. There's no need to create another `NSURL` from it.

Just use `bundleURL`. There is no need for the `eventsFile` variable.

```
override func setUp()
{
    super.setUp()
    let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("meetingexample", withExtension: "ics")
    content = try! String(contentsOfURL: bundleURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've been stuck on this all day.